# Java BitSet strange behavior

Tags: java, bitset

Based on the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#get%28int,%20int%29), the following code should print `6`. However, it outputs `3` for no apparent reason.

```
import java.util.*;
public class BitSetStrangeness{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BitSet foo = new BitSet();
        int[] arbitrary = new int[] {
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
        };
        for (int i = 0; i < arbitrary.length; i++)
            if (arbitrary[i] == 1) foo.set(i);
            else foo.clear(i);
        System.out.println(foo.get(15,21).length());
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain a) why I am seeing this behavior and b) How I can modify the code to fix it so that the extracted Bitset is of length 6 instead of 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length%28%29) :

> Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one.

The length only counts the set bits.

The bits are `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, that is false after the third one, hence the returned length.

You have nothing to do : your bitSet is fine, as would have been clear if you had used the [size](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#size%28%29) method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I was trying to treat a BitSet as if it were a string of bits, and I expected the `get` function with fromIndex and toIndex to behave similarly to a substring function.

Answer (score 0):

Why it should return `6`? Let's see:

1. `foo.get(15,21)` returns word equals `4`. In binary representation it is just `100`.
2. Let's read `javadoc` of `length()` method of `BitSet` class:

> Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one. Returns zero if the BitSet contains no set bits.

Ok, we can now check it for `100`: the highest set bit is `2` (counting from `0`), plus one it will be `3`. Everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc for [BitSet#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#length%28%29),says *Returns the "logical size" of this BitSet: **the index of the highest set bit in the BitSet plus one**. Returns zero if the BitSet contains no set bits.*

In your case the `foo.get(15,21)` gives a `BitSet` :  `[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Hence the result is `2+1=3`.